# How to pass hidden id using Intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have Edittext Activity & I have set Edittext Id in different getter setter class. Now I want to pass Edittext id using intent. I am trying to create a object of getter class but when I am calling getEdittext id it is passing 0 or new value. Can anybody tell me how it is possible.

my code here:

```
 case R.id.setDate:
              Intent passAddTask_Id = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Task_Details.class);
              db = new TodoTask_Database(getApplicationContext());
              tasknote = taskNote.getText().toString();
              db.addTaskNote(tasknote, null, completed);
              AddTask addTask = new AddTask();   //Getter setter class object
              int addtask_Id = addTask.getTaskID();   //getting 0 value
              passAddTask_Id.putExtra("AddTask_Id", addtask_Id);
              startActivity(passAddTask_Id);
              break;
```

Getting Intent:

```
        Intent passAddTask_ID = getIntent();
        int AddtaskID = passAddTask_ID.getIntExtra("AddTask_Id", 0);
```

Comment: What is purpose to send edittext id to another activity? You can not access that Edittext with that id into another activity (if u think)

Comment: I need to save particular Id in different database table so that I can call parameter using same Id.

Comment: in listview we can call id using adapter.getItem(position), But Don't know how to call ID from getter setter class in Activity without adapter. because I am using edittext not listview.

Comment: where did you set id after AddTask addTask = new AddTask(); ?

Comment: that will be dynamic on "setDate" button. Means when anybody click on setDate button particular edittext id will save in database and then that id will call from database table issue I am facing is how to call dynamic id.

Comment: @PankajKumar any idea?

Comment: actually its not clear to me what u r doing with id. id column should be auto increment. and when you insert data into table, insert methods returns the is of newly added row..

Comment: yes exactly, I want that auto incremented id from run time, If id 4 is saving into table then I want that 4 id save into other table as well. how to do that?

Comment: Then make `db.addTaskNote(tasknote, null, completed);` such a way which will return tha same value returned by `insert`. and then you can use that id to send at another activity as `passAddTask_Id.putExtra("AddTask_Id", id_returned_by_insert);`

Answer (score 0):

To get the value, you'll have to use putExtra() like so:

```
 case R.id.setDate:
              Intent passAddTask_Id = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Task_Details.class);
              passAddTask_Id.putExtra("AddTask_Id", 11);
              db = new TodoTask_Database(getApplicationContext());
              tasknote = taskNote.getText().toString();
              db.addTaskNote(tasknote, null, completed);
              AddTask addTask = new AddTask();   //Getter setter class object
              int addtask_Id = addTask.getTaskID();   //getting 0 value
              passAddTask_Id.putExtra("AddTask_Id", addtask_Id);
              startActivity(passAddTask_Id);
              break;
```

From the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) -

> **Returns**
>   the value of an item that previously added with [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) or the default value if none >was found.

After that, when you use:

```
Intent passAddTask_ID = getIntent();
int AddtaskID = passAddTask_ID.getIntExtra("AddTask_Id", 0);
```

You'll get the result of 11, because you have put it with the [putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) method.

Comment: I don't have to use particular value, I want putextra value at run time.

Comment: I think that in this case you'll need to use `passAddTask_ID.getExtras().getInt("id");`. Based on the implementation you provided (the description of the question), you'll need to use `putExtra()` in order to get this "extra" info with the `getIntExtra()` method.

Comment: I know hot to get Intent, but the issue is how to put Intent using run time id. is here any way to get Id at run time?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the values through intent correctly. I think you are getting problems while getting the passed values. Try this and this works for me.

You have to use a bundle for getting the values.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    int addTaskID = b.getInt("AddTask_Id, 0);
```

Comment: No I need ID value from getter setter class

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the Answer here... I need to create query in database, return long in insert method and then call that particular row id.

like this:

```
public long addTaskNote(String taskNote, String TaskList_Id, String taskCompleted) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TASKNOTE, taskNote); // Task Note
    values.put(KEY_TASK_TASKLISTID, TaskList_Id); // TaskList ID
    values.put(KEY_TASKCOMPLETED, taskCompleted); // Task Completed
    // Inserting Row
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_TODOTASK, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
    return id;    //It will give you the return value of id.
}
```

Changes in my code:

```
case R.id.setDate:
              Intent passAddTask_Id = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Task_Details.class);
              db = new TodoTask_Database(getApplicationContext());
              tasknote = taskNote.getText().toString();
              long Addtask_id = db.addTaskNote(tasknote, null, completed);
              System.out.println(Addtask_id);
              passAddTask_Id.putExtra("AddTask_Id", Addtask_id);
              startActivity(passAddTask_Id);
              break;
```

Here you can get id at run time saved value.